# Displaying SQLite database information in a UIText field

Tags: database, sqlite, textfield

I am building a quiz game app and would like to make a method that will pull a question out of a database and display the information in text fields. In my data base I have 7 columns; the Primary ID, Question, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, Correct (indicates which is the right answer)

How would I go about doing this? I've tried several tutorials but they all load the database into a TableView so I am unclear of how to specify a row to load and tell xcode to populate my fields with the proper information.

Thoughts?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you may use foreachloop to display the records from your textboxes.

Here is a sample in c#:

```
private void Loaddatatotextboxes()
{

//your bind stuff to datatable eg DataTable dt = new DataTable()

foreach(DataRow db in dt.Rows())
{

textboxquestion.Text = db["Question"].ToString();

}

}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Crimsonland.

Comment: Try it if you are using vstudio and c#... : )

Comment: I am fairly new to Xcode, I've been cruising along pretty well untill this SQLite problem. Could you elaborate at all on your solution? I hate to be a pain but I've been struggling with this problem for quite some tome now!